# css multiple class / id selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to know how to write a css block that applies to either multiple *ids* or multiple *classes*:

Something like:

```
.class1, .class2 {
 ...
}
```

or

```
#id1, #id2 {
 ...
}
```

I'd like to know how to do both cases (which hopefully are cross browser compliant).  Thanks.

**Update:** To make it more interesting, is this valid too?

```
#id tr, #id2 tr {

}
```

?

Comment: Both your solutions are correct....

Comment: Oh really? I can just comma separate them?

Comment: Yes you can. Visit w3schools for more informations

Comment: Why didn't you just test this?

Comment: Well I don't have many different browser versions and varieties to confirm so I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are looking for something like this :

```
.oddBoxOut, 
.evenBoxOut {
  width: 12em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.oddBoxOut {
  float: left;
}

.evenBoxOut {
  float: right;
}
```

**Update :**

```
p#exampleID1 { background-color: blue; } 
p#exampleID2 { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Comment: For my update, I actually want to select them both in the same block: something like #id1 tr, #id2 tr {} Is that right? Or should it be: tr#id1, tr#id2{} ?

Comment: as per the notation tr#id1, tr#id2{} is right not tried  #id1 tr, #id2 tr {} this one

Answer (score 1):

For your **update** it is also valid,

```
#id1 tr {

}
```

means that every **child** of node id *#id1* will be CSS'ed.

you can do this too

```
tr#id1 {

}
```

Only `tr` will be affected if id == `#id1`