# Combining Elements in CSS

Tags: css, element

How can I combine elements in my CSS? Here's what I've got now:

```
#someID .some-class h1 {
    color: blue;
}

#someID .some-class h2 {
    color: blue;
}

#someID .some-class h3 {
    color: blue;
}
```

and what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
#someID .some-class h1 h2 h3{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to read some CSS tutorial. As your question is basic syntax question [read here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css multiple class / id selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458169/css-multiple-class-id-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Separate the whole selector group with a comma:

```
#someID .some-class h1, #someID .some-class h2, #someID .some-class h3 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I was sure that I tried that method... It worked. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS you'll just have to list all the selectors separated by commas. Note that, again in pure CSS, you'll have to include the whole thing even if part of it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

With Commas

```
#someID .some-class h1, #someID .some-class h2,#someID .some-class h3{
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would target the `class` instead of `id` and `class`. Here is a working example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scarsam/xh1cp6to/)

```
.some-class h1,
.some-class h2,
.some-class h3 {
  color: white;
}
```